# Using Html.BeginForm to post to the current controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a partial that is used in several views.
The partial contains forms. The action when a form is submited is allways the same, but the controller thats contains the action depends on the view.

Lets say I have  Controllers that each have an action ActOnChoosenPerson:

> FireStaffController
>
> HireStaffController

I have a partial

> PersonList.ascx

The forms are rendered as

> Html.BeginForm("FireStaffController" ,
> "ActOnChoosenPerson") or
>
> Html.BeginForm("HireStaffController" ,
> "ActOnChoosenPerson")

What is a good way to get rid of the controller parameter? Right now I pass the name of the current controller into the model and use

> Html.BeginForm(Model.CurrentController ,
> "ActOnChoosenPerson")

but that is a bit awkward.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code will always give your current controller

```
<%=( Url.RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("Controller")) %>
```

Obviously you can use it without the <%= like this

```
Html.BeginForm(
  Url.RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("Controller")) , 
  "ActOnChoosenPerson")
```

It looks more clunky but your model should not need to know what controller is calling it.

Comment: The case of the value returned varies with whatever was in the url in some cases.

Answer (score 7):

ViewContext's [RouteData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.requestcontext.routedata.aspx) property contains names of current controller and action. You could use them like this:

```
Html.BeginForm("ActOnChoosenPerson", ViewContext.RouteData.
    GetRequiredString("controller"))
```

Comment: Nice one, beat me to it by 36 secs. :)

Comment: I prefer this method, but note you have the controller and action params in the wrong order, and the RouteDate.Values indexer returns an object not a string so needs a cast.

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet: Thanks! I have swapped parameters and also changed Values property to GetRequiredString method.

Comment: Have not tested this, but I would suspect this method would honour child action controllers, while @MarkDickinson's does not

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to simply call BeginForm() with no parameters.